# Importing a fixed width txt file into excel whilst transforming the row (date + Totals) into a column

Tags: excel, vba, txt

I hope you can assist me I am a newbie in VBA and have quite extensive knowledge in Excel.
I was wondering what would be the best way to import a fixed width text file into excel and generate the date on a column next to the transactions.

I am able to import the file into excel and place each field on its column however I am struggling to place the date next to each transaction as it is shown as a total at the bottom of each transactions as a total.
Here is a dummy of the file below
P.s the file is not tab delimited

[image: Text file to be imported into excel]

Comment: Would help to add a screenshot of what the data looks like after import to Excel

Comment: Have you tried using powerquery for this?

Comment: Could you post the source text instead of an image and your import code? Basically a formula in the last column is all you need. The formula should test if  "Total" is on the cell of the first column  and if TRUE  grab the date into the formula column and if FALSE  should take the value from the cell bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity lets asume the imported data is in 6 columns A-F, In the total line which contains the date, the first column has something like "Total for ..." and the second column contains the date leading with another text like "... - 18/12/2020".

In  column G of all lines you need the following formula, the code for cell G3:

```
=IF(LEFT(A3,5)="Total",DATE(RIGHT(TRIM(B3),4),LEFT(RIGHT(TRIM(B3),7),2),LEFT(RIGHT(TRIM(B3),10),2)),G4)
```

not using datevalue as I don't know the regional setting format in your PC, but I know the format in your file, which is DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: This is very useful thank you so much. However the totals are at the end/bottom of each transaction list. Do you have an idea which function I can use to populate the date in the rows above the totals column for each section

Comment: The formula is for that, it takes the value from the cell below when is not a total line, put the formula on all the lines above

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportTextFile()

    Dim TXTNAME As String, arWidths, arTypes
    TXTNAME = "fixed width.txt"
    
    ' configuration
    arWidths = Array(15, 25, 15, 15, 15, 15)
    arTypes = Array(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1) '1-general 2-text
    
    Dim arInfo, w, wbText As Workbook, dtTotal As Date
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, p As Long
    Dim colA As String, colB As String, ar
    
    ' determine column positions
    ReDim arInfo(0 To UBound(arWidths))
    p = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(arWidths)
        arInfo(i) = Array(p, arTypes(i))  ' all text
        p = p + arWidths(i)
    Next
        
    ' open workbook
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=TXTNAME, _
        Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=arInfo, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
     
    ' process sheet
    Set wbText = ActiveWorkbook
    With wbText.Sheets(1)
        ' format
       .Columns("C:F").NumberFormat = "0.00"
       .Range("G1") = "Date"
       .Columns("G:G").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
       
       ' add dates
       lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
       
            colA = LCase(.Cells(i, "A"))
            If Left(colA, 5) = "total" Then
                ' extract date from total line
                colB = Right(RTrim(.Cells(i, "B")), 10)
                If colB Like "##/##/####" Then
                    dtTotal = CDate(colB)
                Else
                    MsgBox "'" & colB & "' not a date", vbCritical, "Error row " & i
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                .Rows(i).Delete
            ElseIf colA Like "#*" Then
                ' code matches pattern sarting 0-9
                .Cells(i, "G") = dtTotal
            Else
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
            
       Next
       .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    wbText.SaveAs Replace(TXTNAME, ".txt", ".xlsx")
    MsgBox lastrow - 1 & " rows processed", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```